# Dictionary None value

Tags: python, dictionary

```
f=open("table.txt","r")

a=[]
b=[]
mydict = {}
for line in f:
    a.append(line.strip("\n"))
f.close()
length1=len(a)
for x in range(0,length1):
        b.append(a[x].split("\t"))

for el in b:
    if el is not None:
        k=el[0].strip("")
        v=el[1].strip(" ")
        z=el[2].strip("\n")
        if not k in mydict:
            mydict[k] = {}
            mydict[k][v]=float(z)


        else:
             mydict[k][v]=float(z)

print mydict
```

when I print the dictionary it looks like this

```
{'156.56.250.227 ': {'131.179.150.72': 5.60117197037}, 
'131.179.150.72 ': {'139.19.158.227': 5.99330687523},
'192.33.90.66 ': {'156.56.250.227': 6.74655604362},
'130.195.4.68 ': {'158.110.27.116': 6.19012498856}, 
'202.202.43.198 ': {'192.33.90.66': 6.02898716927}, 
'165.91.55.9 ': {'131.179.150.72': 5.99274086952}, 
'139.19.158.227 ': {'130.195.4.68': 6.90768098831}}
 None
```

I do not know why I'm getting 'None' at the end.My text file looks like this

```
202.202.43.198  192.33.90.66    6.02898716927
156.56.250.227  131.179.150.72  5.60117197037
156.56.250.227  202.202.43.198  6.23671293259
130.195.4.68    158.110.27.116  6.19012498856
165.91.55.9     131.179.150.72  5.99274086952
131.179.150.72  139.19.158.227  5.99330687523
192.33.90.66    156.56.250.227  6.74655604362
139.19.158.227  130.195.4.68    6.90768098831
```

Any clue why I'm getting the None at the end?Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the code snippet you posted is placed inside a **function** body, and you're calling that function with a `print`.

Comment: This is probably not related to your issue, but you can write `k not in mydict` rather than the more awkward `not k in mydict`. Also, rather than parsing a tab separated value file yourself, try using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)!

Answer (score 0):

hcwsha's comment is very probably the right answer, as nothing in your code snippet would print `None`.

Now for something totally unrelated: your code snippet is a very complicated and inefficient way to write this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
with open("table.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                continue
        k, v, z = map(str.strip, line.split("\t"))
        d[k][v] = float(z)

print d
```